# How to run unibootin under mint to make a bootable usb

Tags: usb-flash-drive, linux-mint

I have downloaded unibooton-linux64 under mint 17. I dont see how i can get software manager to open it. Is there another way of running unibootin. to install another linix distro.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the menu and search for "unetbootin" and it shoudl show up and run. It will likely ask for your password to get full access to the machine.